# Auto count by entering number in MS Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking an excel sheet to calculate the total count by automatically.

I am creating an excel for attendance management system. There are about 30 students in the class. They are denoted by their registration number (2011/V/01, 
2011/V/02, ...., 2011/V/30). They have many classes everyday. The attendance (every students put signature in the attendance sheet) is taken every hours by the lecturers. When the attendance sheets reached to the department, the officer ready to calculate the absentees.

The officer'll type the last number of the registration number for the absent students(Ex: 05 for 2011/V/05).

On starts the total absents is in zero.

When he/she inputs the last number in cell A3 and press enter, immediately the correspondent cell should increment by 1.

In first attendance sheet, registration number of 2011/V/02, 2011/V/05, 2011/V/07 and 2011/V/13 are absents

```
(Ex: cell A3 = 02 then cell D3 from 0 to 1).
(Ex: cell A3= 05 then cell D6 from 0 to 1).
(Ex: cell A3 = 07 then cell D8 from 0 to 1).
(Ex: cell A3 = 13 then cell D14 from 0 to 1).


In second attendance sheet 2011/V/03, 2011/V/05, 2011/V/13, 2011/V/16 and 2011/V/21 are absents
(Ex: cell A3 = 03 then cell D4 from 0 to 1).
(Ex: cell A3 = 05 then cell D6 from 1 to 2). (absent in first sheet,so 1 to 2)
(Ex: cell A3 = 13 then cell D14 from 1 to 2). (absent in first sheet,so 1 to 2)
(Ex: cell A3 = 16 then cell D17 from 0 to 1).
(Ex: cell A3 = 21 then cell D22 from 0 to 1).
```

In third attendance sheet 2011/V/03 and 2011/V/05 are absents
(Ex: cell A3 = 03 then cell D4 from 1 to 2). (absent in second sheet,so 1 to 2)
(Ex: cell A3 = 05 then cell D6 from 2 to 3). (absent in second sheet,so 2 to 3)

This'll happen every day until the attendance sheets is computerized.

https://www.flickr.com/gp/93604880@N02/8kv3N0

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Why would cell A3 be greater than `>` D4, D6, etc?  I think you could probably accomplish what you want with `countif()` or `countifs()`.

Comment: A3 = 02 means typing 02 in cell A3.

Comment: How to change, if the Reg. # is 01, 02, 03, .... 29 , 003. Note this : here the Reg. # is only last numbers not (2011/V/). And the last number is "003", it is not 30. 

https://www.flickr.com/gp/93604880@N02/4Q92e6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code module for the data-entry sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim student As String, f As Range

    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Address() = "$A$3" Then

        student = "2011/V/" & Format(Target.Value, "00")

        Set f = Me.Range("C:C").Find(what:=student, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            Me.Range("A3:A4").ClearContents
            f.Offset(0, 1).Value = f.Offset(0, 1).Value + 1
        Else
            Me.Range("A4").Value = "Student not found!"
        End If

        Me.Range("a3").Select

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: ok, here 2011/V/ is not a main part. because i just input  the last two digits only. example 05 for 2011/V/05

Comment: Thank you so much Tim Williams. It's working correctly. You showed the path, what I expected!

Comment: How to change, if the Reg. # is 01, 02, 03, .... 29 , 003. Note this : here the Reg. # is only last numbers not (2011/V/). And the last number is "003", it is not 30. 

https://www.flickr.com/gp/93604880@N02/4Q92e6

Comment: I was trying to make it so you didn't have to enter the leading zeros, but it looks like you need to enter the whole value, so you can remove the `Format()` call from around `Target.Value`

Comment: BTW having both 03 and 003 as two distinct registry numbers seems like asking for trouble, particularly when working in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is best achieved with a very simple *data entry user form*.

Google ***"excel vba data entry user form"*** and you will found excellent tutorials.

Follow them and come back here to keep reading this answer.

I would create two sheets and one form.

Sheet1 would contain a log of your data entry. With just two columns, date and student code.

Sheet2 would contain the absences count. Again with two columns, column one the list of all of your students and colum two the running count of absences.

Form would contain two controls. One, a **single field for the student code** (either a text box or, something more elaborate like a combo box, built at initialize time with all the student codes of column 1 of sheet2). And two, a **submit button**.

On the code for the submit button, you should add some code to take the current date and selected student code, and insert them to the last row of sheet1.

On sheet2, the second column would be a formula, that is simply a count of the lookup results of the corresponding student code into the column 2 of sheet1.